# Cannot build chromium android

Tags: android, android-studio, chromium

I'm trying to build android apk with [instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md)`.

I'm trying to run `gclient runhooks` this command.
but I get this error

```
D:\Android\chromium\src>gclient runhooks
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
            git_cl.py
            tests/git_cl_test.py
    Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
    Aborting
    Failed to update depot_tools.
```

I'm trying to commit, I got this

```
D:\Android\chromium\src>git commit
    HEAD detached at origin/master
    nothing to commit, working tree clean


D:\Android\chromium\src>git stash
No local changes to save

D:\Android\chromium\src>git stash pop
No stash entries found.
```

Please help me to build chromium apk and how to import into android-studio and run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running `git stash` to get your repo back to a clean state. If that doesn't work, see that `git status` shows to see what the local changes are. (To get your changes back after running the hooks, run `git stash pop`)

Comment: I've tried. but i got this `D:\Android\chromium\src>git stash
No local changes to save`

Comment: Try this before running `gclient runhooks`: `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 0):

The error message has an important clue:

> Failed to update depot_tools.

The issue is in the `depot_tools` repository, not the Chromium repository itself.

In the directory where you checked out `depot_tools`, run `git stash` (non-destructive) or `git reset --hard` (destructive). You shouldn't need to do anything in the `chromium/src` directory for this particular error.